# How can I open multiple websites in the same window same tab in batch?

Tags: url, batch-file, tabs, window

I want to be able to open 2 URLs in the same window and tab. For example, I want to open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) first and then [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) right after, but still in the same window and tab. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you mean, two web pages open in the same window and same tab, at the same time?  You can't do that unless you write your own frameset page, and open google in one frame and twitter in another frame...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same window, same tab -- the only way is to create a html page that pulls content from two websites and displays them side-by-side.  A frameset is one way of doing this:

```
<HTML>
  <FRAMESET cols="50%,50%">
    <FRAME src="http://www.ask.com/">
    <FRAME src="http://www.timeanddate.com/">
  </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

However, many websites do not allow their content to be displayed in frames due to security reasons.  Both Google and Twitter block frames...  There may be other ways to accomplish this that are not blocked by websites, like using `<iframe>` elements.  Still, the solution is a static page like the frameset example above.

You could easily write a batch file that would let you pass in two domain names on the command line, the batch file could generate the static html file and then open it, which would display the content of two websites on a single page (as in the example above).